# Changing background and textcolor in CMD using variables C++

Tags: c++, windows, colors, cmd, system

I am new to C++, I have been working in Java for a while, now and I wanted to learn a few more languages. I was making a CMD RPG game. I wanted the user to enter a char to change the color of text and background in the command prompt.

```
char bg,txt;

cout << "Enter your option for BACKGROUND color: " << endl;
cin >> bg;
system("cls");

cout << "Enter your option for TEXT color: " << endl;
cin >> txt;
system("cls");

//here is the part I have trouble on
system("color ",bg,txt);
//
```

Comment: I think you mean that you run your app on windows and not on DOS (as tagged). Am I correct?

Comment: No, it is DOS. I have seen other people do it and I wanted to try it.

Comment: You are confusing things: `cmd` is the command processor of Windows NT based operating systems (Windows NT, 2000, XP, Vista, 7 and 8) and is often used as a synonym for "console (mode) applications" on those Windows versions. That is _not_ DOS. (MS) DOS was the 16 bit operating system that Windows 3.x, 95, 98 and Me were based on. I would highly doubt that you actually meant the old/original DOS. Any way, having both the `cmd` and `dos` tags on the same question doesn't make sense (at least unless you explicitly ask for _both_ operating systems).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I didn't know there was a difference. I am relatively new to programming and computers. I have done it for about 1 3/4 years. I apologize for that. I am wanting to do a Command prompt RPG for windows. I do not want a GUI. It is all text based. I am using special ALT characters that I have successfully implemented into the CMD. But I wanted the user to input a number from 1-9 or a character from A-F (or possibly just 1-15) to change the color of the background and text of the CMD to make it more customizable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code

```
void setcolor(unsigned short color)                
{                                                   
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hcon,color);
}
```

You have 0-15 numbers for colors 0 for black and 15 for white.

just call the function `setcolor(numberOf Color)` before the text you want to color

Comment: Sorry about being a noob, but when I make the function, I get errors. Is there a header I should include to get the HANDEL?

Comment: You need <windows.h> or <wincon.h> (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Yes it is `<windows.h>` for getting hendle

Comment: Thanks, but what about the background. It changes the text but not the background.

Comment: Never mind. If you go past 15 it will change the color of the background, too.